# Is there a way to weight paint such that falloff only affects a contiguous mesh?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, brushes

I am attempting to weight paint a rig whose mesh is made of many loose parts. (I am attempting to import it into a game, and for whatever reason, separating the mesh and parenting the individual loose parts to individual bones doesn't seem to work once I leave blender.)

I would like to be able to weight paint in such a way that the brush falloff only affects the given loose part I am currently painting, without affecting any other loose parts. (that is, I want brush falloff to be limited to the contiguous mesh I am working on.)

Is there a means to do such a thing? I know that what I am asking is possible in Maya, so I assume it should also be possible in blender.

Note that I am not attempting to do anything with automatic weights; I am trying to do this manually.

Comment: How about separate by loose parts ('p'->parts in edit mode) then rejoin when done weight painting?  Any reason that won't work for you?

Comment: How about masking?

Comment: @Nathan last time I tried that, joining the mesh back up undid all of the weight painting.

Comment: @Bruno Masking seems to be a viable solution. I will continue investigating this.

Comment: @Globin347 It shouldn't.  Parent with empty groups first before joining, and join to one of the original objects.

Comment: @Nathan I'll experiment with that in the future, but for now, masking seems to work sufficiently well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems masking works. By going into edit mode and selecting one of the loose parts (click on it, select -> linked -> linked), and then going into weight paint mode, I can restrict the selection to just this one object. It's clunkier than Maya's solution, but It works sufficiently well.